# Search for a value inside of an array and return key

Tags: php, arrays, search

My array looks like this:

```
$myarr = array(
    1 => array(2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11),
    2 => array(95, 5, 8, 15, 21)
);
```

Is it possible to search thru the array for eg. for the `8` and then return the key number under which the value was located?

Eg. `95` is inside of the key no. `2`, then if it does found the `95` it should return `2` - and `FALSE` otherwise. Another example: the `11` was found inside of the key no. `1`, then it should return `1` and `FALSE` otherwise.

Is there a such PHP function for this?

Comment: Have you tried building your own function?

Comment: No, read - I'm asking for a PHP's built-in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for array_walk() and/or array_walk_recursive().

Answer (score 1):

Easy pie... I think you could figured out by yourself...

```
function searchInMyArr($myarray, $search_term){
    $position = false;
    foreach ($myarray as $key => $subarray){
        if (in_array($search_term,$subarray){
            $position = $key;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $position;
}
```

Comment: @AntonioLaguna If the value is in multiple keys, your function will return only the 1st one found..

Comment: @Scott Why slow? Or how fast do you imagine a search in multilevel array? If this is too slow for you, than you need to consider a trade of time-vs-memory, and pre-index the values in advance. But that would be a whole different problem to solve.

Comment: @Scott I don't think that's slow at all. Built-in methods in PHP are quite alike but they are written in C of course...

DainisAbols this wasn't a requirement nor it's common pattern. However, the function can be changed to achive that easily.

Answer (score 0):

No, your case is too specific and unlikely to be used by others, hence it's not in the PHP itself.

Here's a possible solution

```
function search_array_multilevel($needle, $haystack) 
{
    foreach ($haystack as $index => $subarray) {
        if (in_array($needle, $subarray)) {
            return $index;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```